# Before applying for jobs, how do I filter out companies that have a reputation for sacking employees willy nilly?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process

One of the companies I worked for, regularly let go of its employees for trivial or unknown reasons. Within a couple of months of my joining, my team lead was fired for having a 'bad attitude'. In a couple of months, two developers on my team were let go for being incompetent. A team lead of 15 years was let go suddenly for unknown reasons.

I too was eventually fired for talking on my cell phone to a recruiter. Since then, I've worked for few other great end-clients who only let go of its employees for valid reasons; like lack of budget or change of strategy.

But still, I'd like to avoid the first kind of company in my future job searches. What's a good way to find out if an employer has no regard for its employees?

Comment: Talking on your phone with a recruiter during work hours is hardly "willy nilly" reasoning for getting let go, unless you were saying, "please don't call me on work hours, thanks, bye."

Comment: If someone actually IS incompetent or has a bad attitude then surely they deserve to be fired? (after warnings etc)

Comment: You often will not know exactly what happened to cause an employee to be fired as the only person who can talk about it is the person fired and they usually have an ax to grind and consider it unfair no matter how correct the decision was. Management and HR are usually not allowed to discuss personnel issues like that so you may not know about the incident(s) that actually caused the firing. So don't assume that because you did not see a firing offense that there wasn't one.

Comment: @HLGEM While you may not know specific causes it becomes pretty clear, pretty quick if a place practices zero warnings on performance issues.  Someone with no obvious performance issues being fired won't make a pattern but in an environment like that it doesn't take long to get enough data points to connect the dots.

Comment: Just FYI any employer would fire you for actively seeking other employment. I highly doubt someone would say in a review of a company, "This company stinks, they fire anyone for any reason but they were cool when they found me talking to a recruiter."

Comment: @Dan: That's assuming that both companies and employees stick to outdated feudalistic attitudes. A good company would try hard to keep its employees because it values them. If it spots its employees seeking jobs elsewhere, they'd try harder to keep them; because employees are valued and / or they know how to get the most out of their existing employees.

So I would definitely leave or not apply to a company that would fire me for fishing for other jobs.

Answer (score 5):

Glassdoor.com includes external reviews.  Some of the info should be taken with a grain of salt as people may post sour grapes on the way out the door or HR may try to use anonymous feedback to sell the company to prospective hires.  For large companies there will be enough data that outliers can be ignored and you can see general trends.

During the interview process you can ask things like:

- What is the average tenure of people on your team?
- Of the last ten
  people who left the team, how many left for other positions in the
  company versus left the company entirely?

Also during the interview process you should talk to your prospective new team.  With them you can likely be a bit more candid in describing the seemingly random firings at your old workplace and asking about their views on job security.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, you are also interviewing companies.

Here are some things I've learned over the decades:

1. Company is willing to pay significantly more than the standard rate.  This can mean that they're having a tough time getting people in the door.
2. Sites like Glassdoor.com and others
3. Word of mouth in the industry
4. Former or current employees
5. Through your network
6. Trade publications
7. Newspapers

and back to the interviewing part.... ask pointed questions such as:

1. How long have you been with the company
2. How long, on average have most people been with this company
3. Why is this position open (If the last person was terminated, that's a hint)
4. What are three things you like about working for this company
5. Where do you see the company heading.

Remember, you can, and should ask questions during the interview.

Comment: "Company is willing to pay significantly more than the standard rate" My experience is the opposite. Companies that pay more generally have an attitude of wanting to higher quality employees and retain those employees, and furthermore are more likely to be in a good financial position to tolerate temporary underperformance. Companies that pay *less* than the going rate are pretty much the opposite.

Comment: @Muhd Not quite.  in the 1990's A certain telecom company, which was later bought up by one of it's babies, was paying 1.5 times the standard rate as they couldn't get people in the front door.  I specifically said significantly more as opposed to "more" for a reason.

Comment: @RichardU But they were not just firing people left and right either.

Comment: @Chad I was there in 1998, yes, they were, and replacing them with contractors.  The joke was that the company had become Armstrong and Two Temps.

Answer (score -1):

**Glassdoor.com!**

If a company has a history of regularly letting people go for trivial reasons you can bet that those employees are out there letting everyone else know.

Comment: [Here](https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/PAL-Health-Technologies-Reviews-E231825.htm) is an example of where it fails.  The company has a bad rep from this(and rightly so imo) but glassdoor has failed to catch this.

Comment: Like any voluntary review system online it isn't perfect. If you take the time to read the reviews in lieu of just glancing at the star rating you should get a decent idea about what is going on at the company. For the OP's particular question about people being fired frequently for trivial issues, that is something that will show up in reviews themselves.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your answer to explain how to use glass door to do that then

Comment: On the other hand, Glassdoor reviews are frequently one-sided and incorrect. Would you expect anyone who was fired for cause to go there and state that the company was correct to fire him and thus it was a good company? Would you expect people who are angry at being fired to try to bring down the company reputation? I would never even consider believing a Glass Door review for this type of thing..

Comment: See the good company reviews. They rarely have employees talking about being fired. @HLGEM